# MySql query analyzer - free solutions

Tags: mysql, analyzer

Is there a good Query Analyzer for MySQL (that's either free, or has a trial), that can analyse a query and make suggestions for indexes, like the "Display estimated execution plan" in Microsoft SQL Server management studio?

Comment: I take it you are aware of EXPLAIN? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: Yes, however looking for something like the MsSQL version...

Answer (score 4):

You may want to try Percona tools for MySQL. Look at [this article](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2008/11/20/an-alternative-to-the-mysql-query-analyzer/)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe "[MySQL Explain Explain](http://mxx.mnstrl.org)" can help (verbose version of MySQL `EXPLAIN` command, forkable on [github](https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/mysql-xplain-xplain)).

Answer (score 1):

https://enterprise.mysql.com

30 day trial...