# which left join is better in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, join, laravel, laravel-4

I have a `users` table and `follows` table and two models for both. I have user left join to fetch the data from the table, but I am confused to use which model and join table (i.e).

```
$user = Follows::select( 'users.id', 'users.username', 'users.photo' )                              
            ->leftJoin('users', 'follows.fk_users_id', '=', 'users.id')     
            ->where('follows.follower_users_id' ,'=', $id)
            ->get();
```

or

```
$user = Users::select( 'users.id', 'users.username', 'users.photo' )                                
            ->leftJoin('follows', 'follows.fk_users_id', '=', 'users.id')       
            ->where('follows.follower_users_id' ,'=', $id)
            ->get();
```

I am coding this in Follows model But I only need data from `users` table where it meets the condition with `follows` table, need your help as I am new to laravel.

My question is whether to use **Follows model and left join users table** or use **Users model and left join follows table**

Comment: `But I only need data from users table where it meets the condition with follows table`.... in that case, use `inner join`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really tell until you actually analyze the resulting SQL that Laravel/PDO creates under your conditions, i.e. how many rows in each table, existing indexes, etc.  Here's a tip, introduce an error into each of the selects and capture the exception message.  It will contain the raw query which you can fix up and apply to an analyzer, see [MySql query analyzer - free solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056840/mysql-query-analyzer-free-solutions).

Comment: Introducing an error into a query just to get it dumped by the exception is not such a good idea. It's better to listen to the query event and log it `Event::listen('illuminate.query', function ($query) { });` or to use `$query->toSql()` to dump it.

Comment: @Bogdan but I haven't done that and don't know how to in laravel any reference link pls

Comment: @Ronser To listen to events in Laravel check the [Events Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/events). To get the raw SQL query as a string use `->toSql()` instead of `->get()`. For debugging purposes I really like the [Laravel Debug Bar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) which also lists all the SQL query being run by the app.

Answer (score 0):

Both the SQL JOINS are same in terms of SQL but when we look at ORM level in Laravel things change.

If we are using the **Follows** model then you will only be able to call the relationships defined in **Follows** model. If you use the **Users** model then you will be able to use the relationships defined against **Users** model.

**NOTE** Use **explain** in SQL and you will find the query execution path are same.